# How to securly perform arbitrary operations on the value of confidential data in a Solidity smart contract?

Tags: solidity, cryptography, privacy

Consider the following Solidity code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract ConfidentialStorage {
    string confidential;

    function setConfidential(string memory str) external {
        confidential = str;
    }

    function checkCharAt(uint8 i, string memory str) external view returns(bool) {
        bytes memory arrConfidential = bytes(confidential);
        require(arrConfidential.length > i, "Out of bounds");
        return arrConfidential[i] == bytes(str)[0];
    }
}
```

The contract is supposed to perform some checks against the *"confidential" string* (the `checkCharAt()` checks for individual characters in the "confidential" value). The code is all good and works properly; but...

- As in the code, I need to perform the required "checks" against the "confidential" value; thus, seemingly, it needs to be in clear-text: in contrast to the following requirement.
- The sensitive *"confidential" string needs to be in secret*; I could've hashed my "confidential" string, but then I could no longer perform the required "checks" against its value: a barrier to the preceding requirement!

So, how may I have my "confidential" string in secret while also be able to perform the required tests against the confidential value?

Or, how may I provide a [Zero-knowledge proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-knowledge_proof) to the *public* for checking the individual characters in the "confidential" string? (In a Merkle Tree for example, publishing the proofs (to be used by the public) will make it trivial to disclose the "confidential" string, while it's fine to be checked through the smart contract function)

---

I've glimpsed over the [homomorphic encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_encryption), but I don't know if it's suitable for this case, and even if it does, how to implement it for my simple Solidity example?

Comment: Why not use two way encryption ? Moreover, the use case does not seem suitable for blockchain. Ethereum is not made for "heavy" computation.

Comment: @Itération122442 tnx for the reply; in a two-way encryption, the Solidity contract would need to have the "key" provided, to decrypt the data: which would be analogous to publish the key to the public, even if Ethereum were capable!

Comment: The concept of the public key is that is can be public. As long as you do not provide the private key, you are good to go.

Comment: @Itération122442 tnx again, sure thing about the concept of the public key, but how to provide the contract with the "public" key, so that others couldn't decrypt the confidential string (the confidential string needs to be only readable by the smart contract, or else, the smart contract to have a way to securely verify for the individual characters in the confidential string alike the provided code)! or, maybe I don't follow, in which I would appreciate you to provide an example (regardless of Ethereum's capability)

Comment: Never put confidential data on a public place would be a good start to rework your project.